# Need advice choosing wiring configuration for combination pressure and temperature sensor

Tags: sensor, temperature, wiring, pressure, daq

I am currently trying to purchase a combination temperature and pressure transmitter for a project, and it has an option to choose between a 3 wire or a 4 wire configuration. I have attached the link to the datasheet of the transducer which has all its specifications.
https://www.pmc1.com/Customer-Content/www/Products/Files/ATM.1st.T.705a.pdf

Here is the wiring diagram:

[image]

I'll be connecting the pressure sensor to a 9 pin D- sub female connector for an analog input pin on DAQ device. Can anyone help me figure out how I will be able to connect the sensor to the input pin? Here is the link to the DAQ manual: https://d36j349d8rqm96.cloudfront.net/3/6/DEWE-43_user%20manual.pdf
Pages 21- 24 have all the information regarding the sensor connections and the input pin layouts.

I am new to industrial pressure sensors and haven't worked with them much before, therefore any advice will be a great help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

since each DAC port can only read a single signal go with 4 wire 
use the "loop powered measurement" diagram (DAC manual figure 4.2) for each signal.